# Where to publish poems?

Tags: publishing, poetry

I'm looking for a site where I can publish my poems.

I'm not keen on rewards; I just need a place to publish it.

I've found poetry.com that seems to be what I'm looking for but they require a Facebook account to log in and I don't have one (and don't plan to create one).

Comment: What do you mean by "publish"? Could you post them on your own blog?

Comment: Look, you should be a little bit more specific. Otherwise you get a link to http://poetrypoem.com/ (like this one) which every stupid Google search can give you much faster.

Comment: I would recommend https://www.poemist.com if you would like to get feedback from other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Write Out Loud](http://www.writeoutloud.net/public/index.php) is UK based, but it has a nice (though little) poetry community. [LiveJournal](http://www.livejournal.com/) is still limping along, and is still the writing community of choice for a large number of people.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not looking for any rewards as such, I'd suggest signing up for a tumblr or wordpress blog and publish your poems there, and give people the link to your poetry.

Answer (score 2):

Try [duotrope.com](http://duotrope.com) for lists of poetry magazines and websites, paying and nonpaying. Though if you don't care about payment, setting up a free blog of your own would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

While I already know you chose a best answer, I thought I'd still share a site for future visitors to this question. There is a good site where you can post up your original works (whether it be a very long story, very short story, or poetry).

[FictionPress](http://www.fictionpress.com) is a really great site. There is also a review system in place so you can get critique from peers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Jottify

http://jottify.com/

It's pretty easy to sign up there and if you take the time to comment on other people's work you usually get quite a few comments on yours too :)

Answer (score -1):

If you get a Facebook account, you can publish them there, with a built-in audience. I suppose, however, you couldn't be anonymous, and you'd have to collect friends.

Comment: Welcome to WritersSE! The poster has already stated s/he does not wish to open a Facebook account, and no, s/he can't "publish" poetry here. Posting it for critique is not publication. Please read the FAQ to get a better sense of what kind of content is allowed here. http://writers.stackexchange.com/faq